# TSql Sum By Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Ive tried looking at some examples but none really relate to what I am trying to do. In my table I have a column which has the date, and what I would like to do is add up the records by their date. For example add all the records on March 12, 13, 14 etc. So each day should have its date and a counted sum. How would I apply that?

```
SELECT DTTM
FROM 
[Audits].[dbo].[Miscount]
Group by DTTM
Order by DTTM desc
```

Cheers!

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total, DTTM FROM [Audits].[dbo].[Miscount] GROUP BY DTTM ORDER BY DTTM DESC`

Comment: What is the type of `[DTTM]`, `Date` , `DateTime2`, `DateTime`, `VarChar`, `NVarChar` or something else?

Comment: Do you want `0` shown for dates which have no rows, or just skip those dates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the number of each records for each day:

```
SELECT DTTM,COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM 
[Audits].[dbo].[Miscount]
Group by DTTM
Order by DTTM desc
```

Or if you want a sum of a field on each record:

```
SELECT DTTM,SUM(field1) AS Sum
FROM 
[Audits].[dbo].[Miscount]
Group by DTTM
Order by DTTM desc
```

Or if DTTM is a datetime then you can use:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DTTM)) AS DTTM,COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM 
[Audits].[dbo].[Miscount]
Group by DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DTTM))
Order by DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DTTM)) desc
```

Newer versions of SQL Sever will support a Date type, so you can do this instead:

```
SELECT CAST(DTTM AS Date) AS DTTM,COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM 
[Audits].[dbo].[Miscount]
Group by CAST(DTTM AS Date)
Order by CAST(DTTM AS Date) desc
```

Comment: Assuming `DTTM` is of type `DATETIME` this would give counts according to each Date and Time combination.

Comment: Works if `DTTM` is `Date`, but will be wrong or too granular for other types.

Comment: You are correct, but I am assuming DTTM stands for "Day of the month", and is an integer type

Comment: I got the first result and all it did was give me a column with a 1 in each for each record. That would be fine if I could count all the 1's by date.

Comment: No DTTM stands for Date Time and its a column that literally has the date time in it.

Comment: Added third option for when DTTM is a datetime

Comment: Ah! That third option was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Added a fourth option, in case you are using only newer versions of SQL Server which is a little bit easier to read.

Comment: @RobertMcKee I suspect it runs faster too, as well as being easier to read.

Comment: Actually, it appears to my tests that casting to date is actually slower, but it is definitely more readable.  Iterating the cast 100,000 times takes 17.8-18.7 seconds, while iterating the datediff takes 13.4-17.2 seconds.  You'd expect different, but apparently not (on SQL Sever 10.50.2550). On 11.0.3128, both take less than 0.007 seconds, I'm guessing it's optimizing my loop right out of existence.

Comment: Actually after upping the iterations to 10,000,000 on 11.0.3128 -- casting is slightly faster -- 6.083s vs 6.670s.  It wasn't optimizing the loop out of existence, it was just much much faster ~250 times as fast.

Answer (score 0):

If `DTTM` is a `DateTime` type then

```
SELECT
            CAST([DTTM] AS Date) [Date],
            COUNT(*) [Total]
    FROM 
            [Audits].[dbo].[Miscount]
    GROUP BY
            CAST([DTTM] AS Date)
    ORDER BY
            1 DESC
```

would do. Heres [some fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/daffa/1) to demonstrate.